# Why do query results change when using coalesce on a char field in a where clause?

Tags: sql, oracle, char, between, coalesce

I'm seeing some unexpected behavior when querying with a where clause on a coalesced char field in an Oracle database.

It seems that the results of

```sql
CASE WHEN COALESCE(char_field, 'some_val') = 'someOtherVal'
```

are different than the results of

```sql
CASE WHEN char_field = 'someOtherVal'
```

The specific comparisons in which I've noticed this weird output are 'between', 'in', and 'equals'. These are the weird outputs I'm seeing:

1. Between seems to be non-inclusive on the upper end
2. In and equals return false for every comparison

Here's some sql to replicate the weirdness:

```sql
CREATE TABLE delete_me( some_char CHAR(8) );

INSERT ALL   
  INTO delete_me (some_char) VALUES ('1')
  INTO delete_me (some_char) VALUES ('2')
  INTO delete_me (some_char) VALUES ('4')
  INTO delete_me (some_char) VALUES ('5')
  INTO delete_me (some_char) VALUES ('abc1')
  INTO delete_me (some_char) VALUES (null)
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;

SELECT some_char,
  COALESCE(some_char, 'wasNull') AS coalesce_some_char,
  CASE
    WHEN (some_char BETWEEN '1' AND '5')
    THEN 'true'
    ELSE 'false'
  END AS between_1_5,
  CASE
    WHEN (COALESCE(some_char, 'wasNull') BETWEEN '1' AND '5')
    THEN 'true'
    ELSE 'false'
  END AS coalesce_between_1_5,
  CASE
    WHEN (some_char IN ('1', '5'))
    THEN 'true'
    ELSE 'false'
  END AS in_1_5,
  CASE
    WHEN (COALESCE(some_char, 'wasNull') IN ('1', '5'))
    THEN 'true'
    ELSE 'false'
  END AS coalesce_in_1_5,
  CASE
    WHEN (some_char = 'abc1')
    THEN 'true'
    ELSE 'false'
  END AS equals_abc1,
  CASE
    WHEN (COALESCE(some_char, 'wasNull') = 'abc1')
    THEN 'true'
    ELSE 'false'
  END AS coalesce_equals_abc1
FROM delete_me;
```

I would have expected the output of the comparisons on coalesced fields to match those on non-coalesced fields for all operators except IS NULL.

Does anyone have any idea why these results wouldn't match up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in the data type of `some_char`. When a column of type `CHAR` is compared to a string, Oracle blank pads the string to the length of the column (see the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/sql_elements002.htm)). In the tests you are doing, the values match in length (`'1'` vs `'1'`) or are completely different (`'1'` vs `'abc1'`) so everything works fine. However when you use `COALESCE` on a `CHAR` field, the output of `COALESCE` is the fully blank padded column value *returned as a `VARCHAR`* (see the [docs for NVL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions110.htm#SQLRF00684)) and so the comparison string is *not* blank padded, and you are then comparing `'1       '` vs `'1'`, which fails. There are a couple of ways to work around this. You can `TRIM` the output of `COALESCE` i.e.

```
TRIM(COALESCE(some_char, 'wasNull'))
```

or change the data type of `some_char` to `VARCHAR(8)` instead.

I've made a demo of all of this on [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f357b0d6eaf46204777218851b1182db)